# How to add html into the text in a post in power automate

Tags: dynamics-crm

You can use the # and add a link to a record in a post inside the UI in D365 CRM and it displays it as  in the UI

But how do we do this in power automate.

I tried adding html like for notes but it doesnt work:

```
<a href="@{variables('RecordUrl')}"><b>Test</b></a>
```